# (HTML) How to reproduce this nested table?

Tags: html

This is an assignment question.
[image: The table I need to reproduce]

The table above is what I need to make. The table below is what I came up with:

[image: My table]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question Two</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Nested Tables</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Header column 1</th>    
                <th>Header column 2</th>
                <th>Header column 3</th>
                <th>Header column 4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <h4>Row 2: Nested Table 1</h4>
                    <table border="1">                                      
                        <tr>
                            <th>Row 1 Header</th>
                            <td>item</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Row 2 Header</th>
                            <td>item</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Row 3 Header</th>
                            <td>item</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Row 2 - Item 4<br/>A second line</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4>Row 3: Nested Table 2</h4>
                    <table border=1>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Row 1 Header</th>
                            <td>item</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Row 2 Header</th>
                            <td>item</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Row 3 - Item 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
                <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
                <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Row 5 - Last row of outer table</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Two things are different: the font and line spacing of Nested Table 1 and 2.

1. As per the font, is there a way to set a default font for all HTML documents to use? If so, how?
2. For the spacing, I have no idea. I tried all kinds of combinations of `<br>`, `<pre>`, `<div>`.. etc. I'm pretty sure it's not a browser issue that caused the erroneous result (tried multiple browsers--I'm using IE, running on Windows 7). Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You can examine the styling of the original HTML in your browser to see things like fonts/spacing/etc., can't you?

Comment: If all you have is a screen shot then all you can do is approximate it.  If whoever gave you the screen shot wants you to replicate the original code exactly then they should provide you with the original code.

Comment: i forgot to mention this is an assignment question.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this question is getting downvoted? The OP has stated the problem clearly, provided code that gets him close to the solution, and is just asking what he is lacking.

Comment: @MattCremeens: So far the only question I'm seeing here is, "Here's an image of some text, what font is it?"  That's not entirely on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing

Comment: I will say that the font appears to be sans-seriff because it doesn't have the extra markings on the letters. Maybe try out some fonts in Word to see if you can match the font. Maybe arial?

Comment: I'll try. Do you know how to set a default font for all HTML documents to use?

Comment: @David what I see is he has an image he wants to replicate and he has provided a partial solution that nearly replicates it, but not quite, and is asking how he can improve his solution to get closer to the end result.

Comment: @JohnDoe: You can use CSS for that.  Apply a font to the `body` element in a `style` tag and it'll apply to the entire contents of that element.  For the spacing, maybe try some padding (also in CSS)?

Comment: @JohnDoe I would just change the font in your css file or in `<style>` tags if you don't have a css file.

Comment: Style which is what this is; is set with CSS and not markup in modern page construction.  Markup is only used to set the "container/target for the CSS.  Does that give you the hint you need for the "assignment"?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess but the font you're looking for may be "Calibri" or something very similar. You can add the `font-family` as an inline style to your `body` tag and everything in the table will inherit the font.

`<body style="font-family:Calibri;">` and [here's a demo of it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/4rcnof6u/).

The spacing seems fine as is, however if you need to make adjustments you can do so with `padding`, `margin`, or even `cellpadding`.

This will pad the space in all the cells by `10`: `<table border="1" cellpadding="10">`

This will pad the top of the cell by `10px`: `<td rowspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;">`

Answer (score 0):

> As per the font, is there a way to set a default font for all HTML documents to use? If so, how?

If it's something for "all HTML documents" to use, then it would be a browser setting.  You're probably on your own for that one.  But if you want something for all of the content in *this* document to use, that's easy with CSS.  Something like this:

```
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

Putting that in the `head` of the HTML would apply that styling to the entire contents of the `body` tag, including all descendants.  (You can also put the CSS code in a separate file and use a `<link>` tag to reference it in the `head`.  As the code grows in complexity, this quickly becomes a preferred approach.)

> For the spacing, I have no idea. I tried all kinds of combinations of `<br>`, `<pre>`, `<div>`.. etc.

I'd use CSS for this as well.  First, identify the element(s) you want to target.  An `id` or a `class` is often a good approach.  For example:

```
<td rowspan="2" id="column3Cell">
```

Then in the CSS you can target that element and apply styling to it:

```
#column3Cell {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Adjust as necessary.  Since the goal here is to replicate a screen shot as exactly as possible, approximating it is going to take some tweaking and trial-and-error.  But there is *a lot* you can do with CSS styles here.

Comment: Thank you David. All of the teacher's examples seem to have the same font. I'll ask him if his browser uses that font as a default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th>Header Column 1</th>
      <th>Header Column 2</th>
      <th>Header Column 3</th>
      <th>Header Column 4</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">Row 2 - Item 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 -Item 2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Row 2 : Nested Table1
          <br>
          <br>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Row 1 Header</th>
              <td>item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Row 2 Header</th>
              <td>item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Row 3 Header</th>
              <td>item</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>Row 2 : Item 4 <br> A second Line</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <br>
          Row 3- Nested Table 2
         <br>
         <br>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Row 1 Header</th>
              <td>item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Row 2 Header</th>
              <td>item</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>Row 3 -item 2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Row 3 - Item 3</td>
        

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 4 - item 1 </td>
        <td>Row 4 - item 2</td>
        <td>Row 4 - item 3 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Row 5-Last row of outer table</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).